# Boostrap Footer not lined up with content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm trying to make a footer that lines up with the content above.  It does not line up in my browser but does when used in jsfiddle.  The content on my local file the footer text is pushed to the right.  Could it be the difference between hero-unit and row?  I tried to find an answer about the difference but was unsuccessful.

http://i270.photobucket.com/albums/jj107/jdelisle1/bottom.png

http://jsfiddle.net/GrecoISU/yxrjQ/13/

`code`

Excuse the dirty code, I've tried so many things I still have to go and clean it up.

Can someone diagnose my problem?

Comment: hey john, You have excess </div> in your hero-unit class. You might need to check it. Nvm I will post my answer for the style

Answer (score 0):

In my observation, you can style it like this.
In your CSS

```
footer .hero-unit div{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: This did not fix it.  It shifted the footer to the left side of the screen and crated a white div below the footer.